# GridLines in C1 Flexgrid got fade while scrolling horizontally and vertically

Tags: wpf, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have stucked in the issue which looks like that the issue in the style sheet applied to the C1FlexGrid, but it is not the issue of Style applied to the control.

Problem Statement :  when we scrolled the grid in Horizontal and vertical direction the gridlines get faded or we can say it get disappeared and if we set the scroll again to default position then gridlines again appeared in proper manner.

Could any one help out in such scenerio, as we are not able to get anytype of solution, not even the reason behind this issue.

**Technolody used** : WPF
**Language Used** : C#
**Third Party Control for Grid** : WPF Component One -- C1FlexGrid

Please let me know the solution for this issue as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance :)

Amol

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting the UseLayoutRounding to true.

```
c1FlexGrid1.UseLayoutRounding = true;
```

Thanks,
Richa